# python collection of tuples to dictionary

Tags: python

I have the following data structure in Python 3:

```
foo = [(1, 'ADTABC', 7), (3, 'ACHDAT', 8), (1, 'AQNDXB', 15), (2, 'AFTCBA', 14)]
```

The first and second elements of each tuple are guaranteed to be unique together. I want to create a dictionary that has as the key the concatenation of the first and second elements and as the value the third element:

```
{'1ADTABC': 7, '3ACHDAT': 8, '1AQNDXB': 15, '2AFTCBA': 14}
```

How do I achieve this?

Why?  The collection you see is the result of a SqlAlchemy query. The third field is the unique id in the database. I need to quickly and efficiently retrieve the Id given the other two elements. Since these values do not really get updated, there is no need to make roundtrips to the db for the retrieval.

Comment: Can you clarify what the desired outcome would be?  for the first one it should be `1ADTABC: 7`, ??

Comment: *Why* do you need to concatenate numbers and strings in a dictionary key?

Comment: I updated with the requested info. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that without string concat like:

#### Code:

```
foo_dict = {x[0:2]: x[2] for x in foo}
```

String concat is not the best way to go about this since it requires the creation of yet a another object, but does actual create any extra information.  A tuple will use the original objects, but still achieve the need to key a dict.

#### Test Code:

```
foo = [(1, 'ADTABC', 7), (3, 'ACHDAT', 8), (1, 'AQNDXB', 15), (2, 'AFTCBA', 14)]
foo_dict = {x[0:2]: x[2] for x in foo}

print(foo)
print(foo_dict)
```

#### Results:

```
[(1, 'ADTABC', 7), (3, 'ACHDAT', 8), (1, 'AQNDXB', 15), (2, 'AFTCBA', 14)]

{(1, 'ADTABC'): 7, (3, 'ACHDAT'): 8, (1, 'AQNDXB'): 15, (2, 'AFTCBA'): 14}
```

Comment: This does not concat the first 2 elements though.It creates a tuple of 2 elements. The OP stated he wanted them concatenated..

Comment: @StephenRauch, to stop the downvoters, I would also add a short explanation why you should aim *not* to concatenate numeric data with strings. It's a classic XY problem, where OP should explain the *need* for such an ugly construct.

Comment: @jpp, thanks, but whatever.  I got called away to real life. There is only so much one can do to attempt to educate.

Comment: @johnashu, FYI: the OP's desire to to do a string concat does not make it a good idea.  However, still love your enthusiasm.

Comment: @StephenRauch In this instance is it not the only way he can achieve what he desires? I agree string concatenation should be avaoided if possible but what are the alternatives? is the possiblity not there because sometimes it is all one can do?

Comment: @johnashu, No, it is not the only way, as I tried to show.  A tuple is perfectly fine as a dict key.  And is generally preferable as you can simply use the immutable objects in question to build a key, you do not need to use string concat to build something new.  Cheers.

Comment: Which is better for the OP's question. a tuple containing a string and an integer or a single string that has been concatenated?

Comment: The basic problem is that a string concat needs to be constructed.  A tuple is (counter-intuitively) a simpler structure.  So unless you have an explicit need for the string, constructing it is a waste, and therefore less performant, and as such less desirable.  So in this case, if all that is needed is a key for a dict, the tuple is likely a better choice.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, there is no need for concat.

Comment: @Steve Rauch Thank you for taking the time to explain the detail. It has really helped my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
h = {str(a) + b: c for a,b,c in foo}
```

Comment: I think this clearly does what the OP asked.. do people think it requires more explanation?